# Scala Range constructors APIs

Tags: scala

In Scala we can create a Range object by either doing:

```
var range = 1 to 10
```

Or instead using the constructor

```
var range = new Range(1,10,1)
```

However, if we look into the [Scala API for Range](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.Range), we can only see one constructor defined that takes 3 arguments. So my question is: where can we find the API for constructors like the first one? I expected to find this information on the API page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first syntactic sugar is actually achieved with following steps.

Step 1: implicitly convert `Int` to `RichInt` with build-in implicit conversion defined in `scala.Predef`

```
@inline implicit def intWrapper(x: Int)         = new runtime.RichInt(x)
```

Step 2: delegate `RichInt.to` to `Range.inclusive`

```
def to(end: Int): Range.Inclusive = Range.inclusive(self, end)
```

Step 3: construct `Range` object with `Range.inclusive` function

```
def inclusive(start: Int, end: Int): Range.Inclusive = new Inclusive(start, end, 1)

// note Range.Inclusive is a subclass of Range
class Inclusive(start: Int, end: Int, step: Int) extends Range(start, end, step)
```

Comment: Didn't you mean 'syntactic sugar'?

Comment: Lots of things I don't understand there, but I'm only just starting scala. I'll assume the votes your answer received means it's correct. I'll mark your answer as correct and come back in a couple of months when I actually can understand what you wrote. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Max's answer explains how `to` and `until` work, but in the end, your question doesn't really have an answer.  The introductory material on `Range` mentions `until`, but `to` and `until` are not documented there because they aren't constructors or companion object methods of `Range`.  Scaladoc doesn't have a way to connect the indirect path through `RichInt` to the page for `Range`.  Maybe it should.